# Proguard -keepattributes class filter

Tags: proguard

Hello, {username}.

I need to apply the "-keepattributes Signature" for some specific classes. But in all other classes I need to clear Signature. The problem - I can't do it. The documentation contains -if instruction also, but no examples i have found:(

Thank you in advance!